# Error using EmailComposerWithAttachment phonegap/cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm trying to use the Phonegap/cordova EmailComposerWithAttachments [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposerWithAttachments). I've followed the instructions in the readme file to the letter but when try and use the plugin within my JS I get the following error:

```
2013-02-18 10:41:41.743 MyApp[377:907] CDVPlugin class EmailComposer (pluginName: EmailComposer) does not exist.
2013-02-18 10:41:41.745 MyApp[377:907] ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

I'm using Cordova 2.3.0. I've added the MessageUI.framework to the project, added the .h and .m files to the plugins directory and have added:

```
<plugin name="EmailComposer" value="EmailComposer" />
```

To the config.xml file (the readme mentions adding that to the .plist but that doesnt exist past 2.2.0 I believe.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by building a new cordova project. I then hit a bug with a line of code in the EmailCompser.m file with a commend called Dlog, after some Googling I found that chaning that command to NSLog solved the issue and the plugin now works fine - hope this helps someone.